# How to specify "any" value of a property?

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, protege

I assigned a restriction "hasOpeningTime" to a class "CategoryHierarchy".

[image]

It means that all individuals of the class "CategoryHierarchy" must have the property "hasOpeningTime" specified.
There is the following relation:

```
CategoryHierarchy -> hasOpeningTime > Season
```

The class "Season" has the following sub-classes:

```
spring
summer
autumn
winter
```

For example, MountainSnowSports -> hasOpeningTime -> winter.

However, there are many categories that can be assigned to ANY season. For example, an individual of the category "CinemasTheatres" should have any season.
How can I specify it when I create such individuals?

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX owl: <http://test.com/my-ontology.owl#> 

INSERT { 
  owl:act_1 rdf:type owl: CinemasTheatres . 
  owl:act_1 owl:hasOpeningTime owl:* .       // ???
} 
WHERE {
  FILTER NOT EXISTS { 
    owl:act_1 rdf:type owl: CinemasTheatres . 
  } 
}
```

UPDATE:

After reading the comments, I assume that the solution for `CinemasTheatres` would be the following:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX owl: <http://test.com/my-ontology.owl#> 

INSERT DATA { 
  owl:act_1 rdf:type owl: CinemasTheatres . 
  owl:act_1 owl:hasOpeningTime owl:spring .
  owl:act_1 owl:hasOpeningTime owl:summer .
  owl:act_1 owl:hasOpeningTime owl:autumn .
  owl:act_1 owl:hasOpeningTime owl:winter .
}
```

Comment: you're mixing up classes and individuals. you can only make generic statements about classes. on the other hand, in the INSERT query you're trying to add an property assertion axiom (ayes, it's an RDF triple, but in OWL terms a property assertion) about an individual. that's why you have to use an existing individual. I don't understand **why** you want to do this...it follows logically by inference that there is some opening time for any instance of the class, just it's unknown

Comment: by the way, the same as in your previous question. THE INSERT query is useless or better said, the wrong way. it has to be `INSERT DATA {...}` - there is no need for the `INSERT ... WHERE ...` query type here as you don't do any pattern matching.

Comment: @AKSW: Thanks. If I use `INSER DATA`, I should remove `WHERE`, right? But what will happen with possible duplicates? How can I avoid inserting duplicates?

Comment: @AKSW: I made some tests and it looks like `INSERT DATA` identifies duplicates and does not insert them repeatedly.

Comment: @AKSW: Regarding mixing up classes and individuals, I don't get the point. I want to load instances. Some instances like `CinemasTheatres ` should have `hasOpeningTime` assigned to all seasons. Maybe then I should add 4 assertions in INSERT DATA query. Please see my update. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding `INSERT DATA` you forget the most important point I guess. And RDF graph is a **set of RDF triples**. There will never be duplicates

Comment: yes, adding all opening times would avoid this. I just wanted to say, making a generic statement like `hasOpeningTime some season` isn't possible for an individual. (ok, there is OWL punning to use the same URI for a class and an individual, but would't prefer this way)

Comment: just a minor comment. You probably should avoid reusing the prefix `owl` for your own vocabulary as it's usually reserved for the OWL vocabulary. Some tools might do weird things if you're not being careful.

Comment: @AKSW: Ok, thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments of AKSW, the solution to add multiple seasons the instance of `CinemasTheatres` is the following:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX test: <http://test.com/my-ontology.owl#> 

INSERT DATA { 
  test:act_1 rdf:type test: CinemasTheatres . 
  test:act_1 test:hasOpeningTime test:spring .
  test:act_1 test:hasOpeningTime test:summer .
  test:act_1 test:hasOpeningTime test:autumn .
  test:act_1 test:hasOpeningTime test:winter .
}
```